# How to scroll down when i descend in the elements created with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, scroll, scrollbar

I have a list created with ng-repeat and two button to go up or go down. The user can selected any element of the list and go up or go down with the two button.

When i descend the selected element with the button go down, the scroll bar still fixed i can't any more see the selected element.

I want to move down the scroll when the element become hidden.

Comment: Provide your code snippet please... May be a Fiddle would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <div class="panel-body panelBodySelectedData" style="padding-left: 10px">
        <nav>
            <ul ng-repeat="item in resultJson.items" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span2">
                <li class="itemReporting" ng-click="selectItem($index)"  ng-class="{selectedReportingItem: $index==selectedIndex}" >{{item.label}}</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>


$scope.goUp = function(){
    if($scope.selectedIndex > 0){
        console.log('goUp');
        $scope.aux = $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex];
        $scope.selectedIndex -- ;
        $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex+1] = $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex];
        $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex] = $scope.aux;
    }
};

$scope.goDown = function(){
    if($scope.selectedIndex < $scope.resultJson.items.length -1){
        console.log('goDown');
        $scope.aux = $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex];
        $scope.selectedIndex ++ ;
        $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex-1] = $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex];
        $scope.resultJson.items[$scope.selectedIndex] = $scope.aux;
        $location.hash('bottom');

          // call $anchorScroll()
          $anchorScroll();

    }
};
```